# How to ensure lines are closed?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, vertices

I often use closed lines to cut polygons on another layer.  When a line is not closed the cutting operation fails.  Is there an out-of-the-box tool that can easily tell me that a line is not closed and identify the vertices that need closing?

EDIT: Forgot to mention I have a standard license so the solution should work with a standard license.

[image]

Comment: Would using the "Must Not Have Dangles" topology rule help?

Comment: Would you be open to a relatively simple python solution?

Comment: Python or ArcObjects solution is fine. I am looking for a quick click-identify-fix tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the Field Calculator, using an expression like:

```
calc(!SHAPE!)
```

and Codeblock:

```
def calc(shape):
    return arcpy.PointGeometry(shape.firstPoint).distanceTo(arcpy.PointGeometry(shape.lastPoint))
```

Distance > 0 means not closed. Granted, this will not zoom to the offending vertices.

Answer (score 0):

As Maksim suggests, using a Topology with the no dangles rule would be one approach.

Another would be using the COGO Traverse tool, although this would be a bit slow and requires more than Basic licensing. You can load a traverse from a sketch, and then once it's loaded there's a closure button that will tell you how far off it is.

Looking at the sketch properties might also indicate no closure - the first and last vertex coordinates should be the same. In theory first and last will be the only two you need to look at for non-closure. If there's a break anywhere else, it's a multi-part feature, which can be tested for with a quick field calc. That would also be pseudo-nodes under the Topology scenario.

Comment: Topology and COGO seem like expensive solutions to the problem "is the first point the same as the last point"

Comment: @vince They definitely are if you don't *already* have the license level, but the original question didn't specify. Neither are speedy/one-click solutions either if considering that aspect, as I mentioned. But "out-of-the-box *tool*" to me means a button to push, and I'm not aware of any that will do it. ET GeoTools has some things that might, but ideally I'd be looking for a tool called "Close Polyline" where I could select a line and click a button (or have it running and select lines), and it would snap first/last if within a radius or draw the 'missing' segment if not.